# How can i take the element name inside the Html

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

How can i able to find the date format in UTC from the html element 2018-06-14T03:00:00.000Z. I am new in php so i don't know how to grab it.

```
<div class="fi-mu__info__datetime" data-utcdate="2018-06-14T03:00:00.000Z">
      14 Jun 2018 - 18:00
      <span class="fi-mu__info__localtime">Local time</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do it using [find](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find) for getting the div with classname `fi-mu__info__datetime` and then getting the `data-utcdate`:

```
$data = <<<DATA
<div class="fi-mu__info__datetime" data-utcdate="2018-06-14T03:00:00.000Z">
      14 Jun 2018 - 18:00
      <span class="fi-mu__info__localtime">Local time</span>
</div>
DATA;

$html = str_get_html($data);

foreach($html->find('div[class=fi-mu__info__datetime]') as $element){
    if ($element->hasAttribute("data-utcdate")) {
        echo $element->{"data-utcdate"} . '<br>';
    }
}
```

If you only want the first one you could use:

```
echo $html->find('div[class=fi-mu__info__datetime]', 0)->{"data-utcdate"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Carbon for parsing date in php https://github.com/briannesbitt/carbon

```
Carbon::parse('2018-06-14T03:00:00.000Z')->toDateTimeString();
```

Here is the docs
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Not like this i need it using the simple html dom from this element data-utcdate

Comment: Do you need the date passed into your php script??

Comment: https://github.com/petdance/htmlparsing use this for if you want to parse html from php